# How do you handle color change when clicked on notification

Tags: android, android-listview

So in my app. I am showing notifications that come from server. At start they have all in blue color but when clicked on anyone of them its color turns into gray. I have handled this by using `setColor` method. But the problem is that whenever I close my app and start it again, it has the same default(`Blue`) color. I want to make the gray color remained for the clicked (`Read`) one notification. I have used `SharedPreferences` for that but it doesn't work for me. Below is my code. If someone has any code example or any idea please help me. Thanks in advance.

This is my adapter code where I am setting and getting the `SharedPreferences` values:

```
private static SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;
ArrayList<ReadNotifications> listDtails;

public AdatperReadNotification(Context context , ArrayList<ReadNotifications> save) {
        this.context = context;
        this.listDtails = save;
    }



@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View view , ViewGroup arg2) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (view == null)
        {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_readnotificaiton, null);
        }

    mSharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(
                "MyPref", 0);

        ReadNotifications details = listDtails.get(position);

        final TextView date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date);
        RelativeLayout re=(RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.relayout);

        boolean state = mSharedPreferences.getBoolean("true", true);
        int pos = mSharedPreferences.getInt("position", -1);

        if(state!=true)
        {

            date.setId(pos);
            date.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);


        }

        else{
                date.setTextColor(Color.rgb(0,255,255));
        }


        date.setText(details.tvText());

        re.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub




                date.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
                Editor e = mSharedPreferences.edit();

                e.putInt("position", position);
                e.putBoolean("true", true);
                e.commit(); // save changes
                Intent intent = new Intent(context,NewNotification.class);
                v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                listDtails.get(position).isSelected = true;



            }
        });


        return view;
    }
```

And this is my ReadNotifications class:

```
public class ReadNotifications implements Serializable
{

    public boolean isSelected;
    ContentValues colmnValues;  


    public ReadNotifications(ContentValues values  ) 
    {
        colmnValues = values;
    }



    public String tvText() {
        return getValue(colmnValues.get("tvText"));
    }


    private String getValue(Object obj){
        if(obj == null){
            return "";
        }
        return (String) obj;
    }


}
```

**`EDITED:`**

After a little change in `SharedPref` it worked but the problem is now when I select second notification it turns the color of first one to blue and change the second one to gray. It happens when I kill my app. Here is the change

```
mSharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
```

Instead of

```
/*mSharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(
                "MyPref", 0);*/
```

and

```
SharedPreferences.Editor e = mSharedPreferences.edit();

                e.putInt("position", position);
                e.putInt("true", 11);
                e.commit(); // save changes
```

and `if condition` now looks like

```
int state = mSharedPreferences.getInt("true", 0);
        int pos = mSharedPreferences.getInt("position", 0);


if(state==11 && pos==position)
        {


            date.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);


        }
```

Comment: Are you populating the listview from a database?

Comment: I think it will be better to keep a field in table for the clicked item.WHen u click the item update  corresponding row and notify the adapter.In getView() check whether corresponding field in your array list and bind to ui.Getting value from sharedpreference to bind values in the row isnt a good practise.